# How to remove styling inherited from anchor tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have seen this question asked before, but none of the solutions seem to work for me or are using an "href", not a "link_to" in Rails, like I am.

I am trying to make my entire card clickable, I have done this by wrapping the contents in a "link_to". The problem is that all the text in the card is appearing as links by inheriting the "a" element's properties.

Thanks!

`

```
  <div class="container-cards">
    <% @challenges.each do |challenge|%>
      <%= link_to(challenge_path(challenge), class: "test") do %>
      <div class="card-challenge">
          <img src= "<%= challenge.poster_url %>", alt="Challenge poster">
        <div class="card-challenge-infos">
          <div>
              <h2> <%= challenge.title %> </h2>
              <p> <%= challenge.description %> </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-challenge-category">
            <%= challenge.category %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

`

I have tried turning setting text-decoration to "none" on the h2 and p elements, turning off inheritance, and setting a tags to inherit all properties of parent to avoid it passing on its own attributes. But none of this has worked, any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the styling to "none" on the anchor tag. Here is an example;

```css
.parent {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #efefef;
  /* unset <a> styling */
  text-decoration: unset;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="parent">
    <span>Text in anchor tag</span>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <span>Default Text in anchor tag</span>
</a>
```

In your case;

```
.test {
  /* ... your other style */
  text-decoration: unset;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much! Just so it's clear in my mind, why does "text-decoration: none" not remove the styling of the anchor tag but :"text-decoration: unset" does?

Comment: "none" also works, it overwrites the user agent style by setting it to none. However "unset" will undo the user agent style and set it to neutral so to speak. Both are viable.

Comment: Hmm, "none" seemed to have no affect. But, "unset" works!